# Is it possible to search string in file and display filename as variable in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

Im trying to search for files as a batch kinda like when your in a folder and you can type what your looking for and it will display names of files with that sting within that file but I want to use it as a variable in a batch

Kinda like

```
 @echo off
:Start  
Title Details Search

set /P "result1=Number1" 

for /f %%i in ('findstr /i "%result%" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Folder\*"') do @echo %result1% found in %%~nxi

set /P "result2=Number2: " 

for /f %%i in ('findstr /i "%result2%" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Folder\*"') do @echo %result2% found in %%~nxi

Pause
```

It wont allow me to do more than one, where the one below works great with a special thanks to Gerhard Barnard but its only one

```
@echo off
:Start  
Title Details Search

set /P "result=what would you want to search today?: " 

for /f %%i in ('findstr /i "%result%" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Folder\*"') do @echo %result% found in %%~nxi
Pause
```

The outcome im trying to get is something like

Bob 543-434-4324
Tom 234-253-2463

Where the name is the filename and the number is what I typed it. So if I type it in the number it will display next to the filename it found
Note- These are not real numbers I just typed random numbers

Comment: Do you want to search directory or directory with subdirectories recursively?

Comment: Im sorry, I don't understand your question. I looking to really only to search within the folder I choose but there will be multiple files within and im not trying to search the filename its self. the file name could be test.rtf but I want to search the words within and it to reply the filename it has found

Comment: So if I had like a contact list. I had names as filenames and phone numbers inside I could search a number and get a name. So filenames could be Tom.rtf, Bob.rtf but if I type a number in the search it will pop up as their name instead of searching their name

Comment: ok, but keep in mind, we can only access files that are pure text, we cannot do this with files like xls for instance as we cannot brute force it using batch. See below answer.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `FindStr /?` to read the usage information. For example, `Findstr /IMC:"String" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\*.*"`. Then read the usage information returned from `For /?`, with special reference to `For /F`, to learn how to run the `FindStr` command in a loop to output the results in a format you can set to one or more variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per your change in question, searching for multiple numbers. You need to add your text seperated by a whitespace in your search. i.e `09122 123441 881992`

```
@echo off
:Start  
Title Details Search

set /P "result=what would you want to search today?: "
for %%a in (%result%) do (
    for /f %%i in ('findstr /i "%%a" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Folder\*.rtf"') do @echo %%~nxi %%a
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I just got it to work, but if im doing more than 1 ik I have to do result1 2 3 but does that mean I cannot use the end result as a variable?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by your comment by editing your question and explaining. I suggest you give some sample input and expected output data.

Comment: Like if im trying to search more than one number at a time

Comment: But you did not specify that in your initial question, so your question is changing now.

Comment: Sorry I figured I could add numbers to it like how you do set /p Number1=Number1: so on so on.

Comment: Like 5, I also changed the question at the top to try to explain better. Im sorry to kinda change what im asking but you are very helpful. I wouldn't have figured that out myself. I tried to for a couple days looking it up but nothing like that popped up

Comment: Omg your really smart dude! You are the most helpful guy I have met on here. Thank you so much! And the only thing im trying to figure out is why it pops up some names and others it pops up "Lang9" and theres no text file named that

Comment: there must be something with that name in it. Keep in mind, we are searching all files. Do your files you search in all have the same extension, if so, what are they? are they `.rtf` files?

Comment: All the files are rtf. I just looked it and it messed up on the ones that have numbers in the Filename bc I have some people from the internet on the list too

Comment: I changed the code to search `.rtf` files only. So please copy the code again.. Unfortunately I cannot help with your file mess :) Also, if you feel this answer solved your issue, please consider selecting it as the correct answer by ticking the grey tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much! One last question, How did you learn all this? And what would be the best way to learn a normal coding language such as Python without going straight to school?

Comment: batch is not a programming language as such, it is more a batch of commands. You can learn most of the batch scripting by reading the help on your computer. You can simply open `cmd.exe` type `help` look at the commands and then if you find any of interest, you can simply type `commandname /?` to see the help. for instance we used `for` in this excercise, so you can do `for /?` to see it's help. Python, perl etc you can find loads of info. i.e this [link for python](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) and [this one for perl](https://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html/)